# How to edit button text in same place in python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am building a 8 puzzle solver in tkinter and I want it to be user interactive like user can change the states accordingly .
So I have created a window with button like below  [image]

Now want that if I click on button 1 it should become editable like user can change the text of that button . Can you please tell me how can I do that ?
Here is the code for creating the window and adding buttons . Sorry , It is a bit messy .

```py
from tkinter import *

window  = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.resizable(0,0)

btn_frame = Frame(window , width = 500 , height = 500 , bd = 2)
btn_frame.pack()
one = Button(btn_frame, text = "1" , width = 10 , height = 3)
one.grid(column = 0 , row = 0 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)
two = Button(btn_frame, text = "2" , width = 10 , height = 3)
two.grid(column = 1 , row = 0 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)
three = Button(btn_frame, text = "3" , width = 10 , height = 3)
three.grid(column = 2 , row = 0 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)

four = Button(btn_frame, text = "4" , width = 10 , height = 3)
four.grid(column = 0 , row = 1 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)
five = Button(btn_frame, text = "5" , width = 10 , height = 3)
five.grid(column = 1 , row = 1 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)
six = Button(btn_frame, text = "6" , width = 10 , height = 3)
six.grid(column = 2 , row = 1 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)

seven = Button(btn_frame, text = "7" , width = 10 , height = 3)
seven.grid(column = 0 , row = 2 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)
eight = Button(btn_frame, text = "8" , width = 10 , height = 3)
eight.grid(column = 1 , row = 2 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)
nine = Button(btn_frame, text = "" , width = 10 , height = 3)
nine.grid(column = 2 , row = 2 , padx = 1 , pady = 1)


list = [[one , two , three ], [four , five , six] , [seven , eight , nine]]

#window.after(5000 , window.destroy)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"click on button ... become editable"***: A `Button` widget is not editable, you have to open a `Entry` on top of the clicked `Button`, input and update the `Button` text on `<Return>`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact a `Button` is just a different looking `Label` with a`command` argument automatically bound to `<Button-1>` event (which is a single left mouse button click); I'll use a `Label` to demonstrate how `Entry` overlaying actually solves your issue.

Basically, I'll create a custom widget inheriting from `Label`, which looks like a `Button`, and when clicked turns into an `Entry` that accepts text. When the user press `Enter` on the `Entry` it's value is transferred to the `Label` and the overlay `Entry` disappear from view. To define that custom widget I'll take advantage of object oriented paradigm (OOP) and its inheritance concept.

Once done, in your code you will just need to use `WriteLabel` instead of `Button`. If you then need further customization of the behaviour of the "Buttons" you can modify the `edit` method: directly or by deriving a new widget that overrides the `edit` method (maybe using the one implemented by its ancestors before defining its own behaviour).

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Label, StringVar
from typing import Any, Dict, Tuple


class WriteLabel(Label):
    """
    Just a writable label widget.
    """

    def __init__(self, master: Any = None, *args: Tuple[Any], **kwargs: Any):
        """
        Constructor.

        :param master:  The parent of the widget.
        :type master:   Any.

        :param args:    Additional positional arguments.
        :type args:     Tuple[Any].

        :param kwargs:  Additional keyword arguments.
        :type kwargs:   Any.
        """
        super().__init__(*args, master=master, **kwargs)

        self._parent = master
        self._value = StringVar()
        self._entry_value = StringVar()

        if 'text' in kwargs:
            self._entry_value.set(value=kwargs['text'])

        self.config(
            textvariable=self._value,
            relief='raised'
        )

        self._entry = Entry(
            textvariable=self._entry_value,
            justify='center'
        )

        self.behaviours()
        self.update()

    def behaviours(self) -> None:
        """
        Sets the binding for interested events by defining in fact the behaviour of the widget.

        :return: None.
        :rtype: None.
        """
        self.bind('<Button-1>',self.edit)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.save)
        self._entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.save)
        self._entry.bind('<Return>', self.save)

    def edit(self, _) -> None:
        """
        It place the entry as overlay on top of the current widget.

        :param _:   The event object [unused].
        :type _:    Event.

        :return: None.
        :rtype: None.
        """
        self._entry.place_forget()
        self._entry_value.set(value=self._value.get())
        self._entry.place(
            x=self.winfo_x(),
            y=self.winfo_y(),
            width=self.winfo_width(),
            height=self.winfo_height()
        )
        self._entry.focus_set()

    def save(self, _) -> None:
        """
        It hides the entry and copy its actual value to the current widget.

        :param _:   The event object [unused].
        :type _:    Event.

        :return: None.
        :rtype: None.
        """
        self._entry.place_forget()
        self._value.set(value=self._entry_value.get())
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tkinter import *

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Application')
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    btn_frame = Frame(window, width=500, height=500, bd=2)
    btn_frame.pack()

    one = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="1", width=10, height=3)
    one.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=1, pady=1)
    two = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="2", width=10, height=3)
    two.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=1, pady=1)
    three = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="3", width=10, height=3)
    three.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=1, pady=1)

    four = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="4", width=10, height=3)
    four.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=1, pady=1)
    five = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="5", width=10, height=3)
    five.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=1, pady=1)
    six = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="6", width=10, height=3)
    six.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=1, pady=1)

    seven = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="7", width=10, height=3)
    seven.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=1, pady=1)
    eight = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="8", width=10, height=3)
    eight.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=1, pady=1)
    nine = WriteLabel(btn_frame, text="", width=10, height=3)
    nine.grid(column=2, row=2, padx=1, pady=1)

    items = [[one, two, three], [four, five, six], [seven, eight, nine]]
    [i.save(None) for j in items for i in j]

    window.mainloop()
```

Here a gif gift show how it looks and works on Windows 10:

[image: Demonstration in action]